# iPhone Xcode Settings.bundle Plist

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode3.2, settings.bundle, iphone-sdk-4.1

I followed the tutorial: http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2010/5/18/adding-a-settings-bundle-to-an-iphone-app.html

And the Toggle Switch (that I just created based on the tutorial) was not in the Settings App. Every time I did an NSLog on the state of the switch, it would return "(null)".

Please help as I need to create, and access a Toggle Switch created in the .plist file. I am new to iPhone Programming.

Here's the code I'm using to set the user preference switch:

```
// Set the application defaults
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSDictionary *appDefaults = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"YES" forKey:@"ShuffleToggleKey"];
[defaults registerDefaults:appDefaults];
[defaults synchronize];
```

And here's the code I'm using to get the state of the user preference switch:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
BOOL enabled = [defaults boolForKey:@"ShuffleToggleKey"];
```

My Settings bundle Root.plist file looks as follows:

[image]

Comment: Please post some example code as to how you're accessing the settings.

Comment: Would you also post your Settings.bundle's *.plist file. (I found that to be a bit tricky the first time.)

Comment: You can copy and passt the "imgur" link into your browser to see me Root.plist file.

Comment: I edited the post to show the imgur link as an image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that, as the tutorial says, you tell the app that you're creating a plist for iPhone settings:

> Select the Root.plist file, click on
>   the Root entry in the detail view to
>   ensure it is selected and then from
>   the Xcode view menu select Property
>   List Type -> iPhone Settings plist.

To set the application defaults, you might consider trying this code instead:

```
// Set the application defaults
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setBool:YES forKey:@"ShuffleToggleKey"];
[defaults synchronize];
```

This will initialize a default database on the user's phone, and take care of preference storage for you.